# como contar espacios en shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Hola estoy empezando a programar cadenas en shellscript, necesito que mi programa pueda contar los espacios vacíos que haya en una cadena pero no se como hacerlo.
Intente hacerlo con:

```
wc -w
```

que cuenta palabras y descontarle 1 pero no me sirve si en la cadena tiene dos espacios vacíos juntos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En `bash`, nos podemos apoyar en las herramientas para [manipular cadenas](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), por ejemplo:

```
mi_cadena="prueba  <-dos_espacios <-aqui_otro"
tmp="${mi_cadena//[^ ]}" # Eliminamos todo lo que no sea espacio
echo "${#tmp}"           # Contamos los mismos
```

Otras formas, pero implican usar herramientas adicionales:

```
grep -o ' ' <<<"$mi_cadena" | grep -c .

tr -dc ' ' <<<"$mi_cadena" | awk '{ print length; }'

tr -dc ' ' <<<"$mi_cadena" | wc -c
```

Fuente: [Count occurrences of a char in a string using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679369/count-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string-using-bash)

Comment: la versión de Awk no es correcta, pues elimina internamente los espacios de más (haz la prueba, `awk -F' ' '{print NF}' <<< "hola         adios"` da apenas 2, que es el número de palabras). Si eso, podrías usar `awk -F'//' '{print gsub(/ /, "")}' <<< "hola         adios"`, que cuenta cuántas veces se ha sustituido el espacio.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', es cierto lo que decís, el ejemplo que usé me indució al error en el caso del awk. NF=Numero de filas.

Answer (score 2):

Contar espacios con las herramientas que nos provee GNU/Linux es un tanto sencillo.

Quizás sea mejor idea utilizar una herramienta en lugar de dos o más, ya que la labor es bastante trivial.

Dos herramientas que abordaremos serán:

- **AWK**
- **Perl**

## 1. Preparando nuestro ejemplo

Para poder operar en todas las siguientes aproximaciones, tomemos por ejemplo la cadena:

```
'  uno dos   tres '
 ||___|___|||____|__ 7 espacios
```

Construir esta cadena de **7 espacios** nos permitirá probar nuestras estrategias ya sea con uno o mas espacios contiguos.

Notemos como la salida del comando `od` nos arroja mas información respecto a la cadena construida para el ejemplo:

```
$ od -cb <<< '  uno dos   tres '
0000000           u   n   o       d   o   s               t   r   e   s
        040 040 165 156 157 040 144 157 163 040 040 040 164 162 145 163
0000020      \n
        040
```

## 2. Usando awk

En otras de las publicaciones se han referido ciertas variables especiales de `awk` (específicamente **GNU/AWK**, o **GAWK**), tales como:

- `RS`, especifica el separador de registros (o "renglones")
- `RT`, contiene el texto de entrada que coincide con el texto denotado por `RS`
- `FS` (se puede definir también con el parametro `-F`), contiene el separador de campos

En [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373255/contar-cuanto-se-repite-una-letra-sin-importar-si-es-may%C3%BAscula-min%C3%BAscula-o-con) publicación se definió la variable `RS` como una expresión regular que encontraba cualquier letra y de esta manera cada letra se tomaba como un registro diferente.

Por otro lado, se utilizó la variable `RT` para actuar si este separador era un carácter deseado; en nuestro caso sería un espacio que, al encontrarse, aumentara la variable conteo en 1.

En el bloque final se mostrara lo acumulado:

```
$ awk -v RS="(.)" 'RT ~ / /{conteo++}END{print conteo}' <<< '  uno dos   tres '
7
```

Utilicemos otra aproximación con el parámetro `-F` que permite definir el separador de campos (`FS`).

Si definimos el separador de campos como alguna expresión regular como:

- `[[:blank:]]`, que busca **un carácter como espacio o tab**
- `( )`, que busca sólo **un espacio**

entonces podemos suponer que el numero de campos sera de la cantidad de separadores mas uno, entonces la cantidad de separadores (espacios) sera la cantidad de campos menos 1, es decir: `NF-1`.

Probemos con nuestra primera aproximación:

```
$ awk -F "[[:blank:]]" '{print NF-1}' <<< '  uno dos   tres '
7
```

Intentemos con la segunda:

```
$ awk -F "( )" '{print NF-1}' <<< '  uno dos   tres '
7
```

Esto tendrá el mismo resultado definiendo la variable `FS` como alguna de nuestras elecciones previas (e.g. `awk -v FS="[[:blank:]]" ...`).

## 3. Utilizando Perl

Con Perl podemos imitar el comportamiento de nuestro ejemplo anterior con awk:

```
$ perl -lne 'END {print $conteo} ++$conteo while / /g' <<< '  uno dos   tres '
7
```

## 4. Nota final

Podemos notar que GNU/Linux nos proporciona herramientas para buscar caracteres sin necesitad de utilizar más de una herramienta.

Esto en algunos casos puede ser conveniente debido a la gran cantidad de caracteres a filtrar; en otros casos pudiera ser contraproducente debido a que requiere,  además labor de investigación para casos sencillos como los tratados en esta publicación, un tiempo más para pensar en su implementación.