# contar cuanto se repite una letra sin importar si es mayúscula, minúscula o con acento?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, grep

¿Cómo podría saber cuándo se repite una letra en una cadena? Utilicé grep:

```
echo "hola mundO" | grep -o "o" | wc -l
```

con esto me aparece la cantidad de veces que aparece "o" pero no reconoce a "O" y si hubiera "ó" tampoco lo reconocería.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que reconozca cualquier letra que este en mayúscula, minúscula o con acento?

Comment: sería bueno presentar un [mcve]: qué tienes, qué quieres que salga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trataré de dar algunas modificaciones a las respuestas ya dadas.

## 1. Utilizando `awk`

Primero intentemos hacer el pequeño script de `awk` un tanto mas flexible:

```
$ awk -v FS='' 'END { 
     for (l=1;l<=NF;l++) 
         if (tolower($l) == "ó" || tolower($l) == "o" )
             conteo++ 
     print conteo
 }' <<< 'hola mundO'
```

Lo que hacemos en este script es pasar como parametro (con el uso de la opción `-v`) `FS` (de *field separator*) como la cadena nula, para iterar sobre los caracteres como si fueran campos.

Entonces dentro del codigo sólo iteramos sobre los caracteres, los convertimos a minusculas y en cualquier coincidencia con la letra deseada añadira un 1 a nuestra variable conteo que al final imprimiremos.

Lo que utilizamos en `... <<< 'hola mundO'` se le llama *here-string*.

Sería buena idea [leer documentación](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) sobre esta característica tan útil.

### 1.1 Poniéndonos locos con `awk`

El siguiente caso elaboraremos nuestro comando semejante al anterior pero usando un tanto algunas características mas precisas y no tan utilizadas de `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS="(.)" 'RT ~ /[oOóÓ]/{conteo++}END{print conteo}' <<< 'hola mundO'
```

Revisemos esta parte:

- Podemos ver a simple vista que seguimos utilizando el parametro `-v` pero esta vez para definir la variable `RS` (de *record separator*).

  Y aquí acabamos de hacer un trucazo que consiste en definir esa variable como una cadena de mas de un caracter.

  [En la documentación de `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html), se indica que el `RS`, es decir, lo que indique que estamos ante un nuevo registro o renglón, sera una expresión regular si la variable se define con una cadena de mas de un caracter (lo cual hicimos).

  Entonces, esta expresión regular la definimos como `(.)`, es decir, cualquier caracter sera tomado como un separador de registros iterando linea por línea.

  Iterando y tomando caracter por caracter nos saltamos el bucle `for`.
- Ya que podemos prescindir del bucle, podemos comparar registro por registro, es decir, letra por letra haciendo que cada una sea un registro diferente.

  Esto lo hacemos sencillamente con `RT ~ /[oOóÓ]/` en donde comparamos el registro completo, dado por nuestra expresión regular (osea, un caracter), almacenado en la variable especial `RT`.

  Lo comparamos con la expresión regular `[oOóÓ]` para que busque ya sea o una "o" mayúscula o minúscula, con o sin acento.
- Si esta búsqueda tiene coincidencia, entonces se ejecuta lo que esta en el bloque de código: `{conteo++}` en el cual la variable `conteo` (inicialmente supuesta como 0) aumentara de 1 en 1.
- El bloque `END` se ejecutara cuando los registros se hayan agotado, en este caso se imprimira únicamente el valor de la variable `conteo`.

El truco de esto es tanto usar la expresion `(.)` como separador, y la variable `RT` que almacena lo encontrado por el patrón (ya sea el caracter como separador o lo encontrado en la expresión regular).

En ambos casos su salida es:

```
$ <opcion que desees>:
2
```

## 2. Utilizando `grep` y expresiones regulares

En este caso juguemos un poco con las potencialidades de `bash`:

```
$ wc -l < <(grep -Eo '[oOóÓ]' <<< 'hola mundO')
```

Revisemos el código mas de cerca:

- `wc -l` cuenta las lineas provenientes de la salida estandar del *process substutition*
- `<(...)` que contiene la expresión
- `grep -Eo` que nos permite utilizar expresiones regulares extendidas y mostrar cada coincidencia (en una línea separada) con el patrón dado en la expresión regular
- `[oOóÓ]` que coincide con "o" o con "O".

La salida de este comando es:

```
$ wc -l < <(grep -Eo '[oOóÓ]' <<< 'hola mundO')
2
```

### 2.1 Utilizando `grep` en *case-insensitive*

Podemos utilizar el parametro `-i` de `grep` que indica que la búsqueda del patrón sera insensible a la capitalización.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente caso:

```
 $ wc -l < <(grep -io '[oó]' <<< 'hola mundOoóóÓÓ')
 7
```

Comment: nótese que es buena práctica en los contadores de Awk imprimir `contador+0` para que en caso de que no haya resultado al menos devuelva un 0.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar Awk para pasar a minúsculas, `fold -w1` para imprimir un carácter cada vez y luego mezclar `sort` y `uniq` para ver las ocurrencias de cada carácter.

```
$ echo "hola mundO" | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | fold -w1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
   2 o
   1 u
   1 n
   1 m
   1 l
   1 h
   1 d
   1 a
   1
```

Por trozos

```
$ echo "hola mundO" | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
hola mundo
$ echo "hola mundO" | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | fold -w1
h
o
l
a
 
m
u
n
d
o
```

---

También puedes hacerlo íntegramente con Awk:

- gensub y tolower para minúsculas y poner cada carácter en una línea
- vector `char[]` para acumular cuántas veces ha salido cada carácter

```
$ echo "hola mundO" | awk '{d=tolower($0);print gensub(/(.)/,"\\1\n", "g", d)}' | awk '{char[$1]+=1} END{for (i in char) print i, char[i]}'
u 1
 2
h 1
l 1
m 1
n 1
a 1
o 2
d 1
```

Comment: Para el tema de las tildes habría que hacer un mapeo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar expresiones regulares con el parámetro `-E`. Para reconocer las variantes de esos caracteres que son diferentes puedes utilizar un conjunto en la expresión. Así quedaría:

```sh
$echo "hola mundO" | grep -o -E "[oOóÓ]" | wc -l
```